# Proper use of Physics.aabb.union()

Tags: javascript, aabb, physicsjs

I'm learning [PhysicsJS](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/), and I tried using [union](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/docs/#Physics-aabb-union) like so:

```
// Window bounds
var rect1 = Physics.aabb(0, 100, 300, 200);
var rect2 = Physics.aabb(100, 0, 200, 300);
var viewportBounds = Physics.aabb.union(rect1, rect2);

// Constrain bodies to these bounds
world.add(Physics.behavior('edge-collision-detection', {
  aabb: viewportBounds,
  restitution: 0.99,
  cof: 0.99
}));
```

but the ball just falls through the bottom.

```js
Physics(function(world){

  var viewWidth = 300;
  var viewHeight = 300;

  var renderer = Physics.renderer('canvas', {
    el: 'viewport',
    width: viewWidth,
    height: viewHeight,
    meta: false
  });

  // add the renderer
  world.add(renderer);
  // render on each step
  world.subscribe('step', function(){
    world.render();
  });

  // Window bounds
    var rect1 = Physics.aabb(0, 100, 300, 200);
    var rect2 = Physics.aabb(100, 0, 200, 300);
    var viewportBounds = Physics.aabb.union(rect1, rect2);
  
  // Constrain bodies to these bounds
  world.add(Physics.behavior('edge-collision-detection', {
      aabb: viewportBounds,
      restitution: 0.99,
      cof: 0.99
  }));

  // Add the ball
  world.add(
      Physics.body('circle', {
        x: 0, // x-coordinate
        y: 0, // y-coordinate
        vx: 0.2, // x-velocity
        vy: 0.01, // y-velocity
        radius: 2.0
      })
  );

  // ensure objects bounce when edge collision is detected
  world.add( Physics.behavior('body-impulse-response') );

  // add some gravity
  world.add( Physics.behavior('constant-acceleration') );

  // subscribe to ticker to advance the simulation
  Physics.util.ticker.subscribe(function( time, dt ){

      world.step( time );
  });

  // start the ticker
  Physics.util.ticker.start();

});
```

```css
body {
  /*background: #121212;*/
}
.pjs-meta {
  display: none;
}

#viewport {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/assets/scripts/vendor/physicsjs-0.5.0/physicsjs-full-0.5.0.min.js'></script>

<canvas id="viewport" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

I can't find any code on GitHub or anywhere using it. Can someone lend some guidance, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was working with a super old version ([physicsjs-0.5.0](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/assets/scripts/vendor/physicsjs-0.5.0/physicsjs-full-0.5.0.js)). I linked to the latest version ([physicsjs-0.7.0](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/assets/scripts/vendor/physicsjs-current/physicsjs-full.js)), which has **much** more functionality (4,088 new lines of code between those two versions). I had to refactor my code a bit to match the updated spec, but it's all good!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find any code on GitHub or anywhere using it. Can someone lend some guidance, please?

You might try reading the [unit tests in the .spec, on Github](https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/blob/509362fd35abfc5959ad18d1ea824550de4e8ed4/test/spec/aabb.spec.js).

Sample test, which should look very readable even if barely know Javascript:

> ```
> it("should initialize provided a width/height and point", function() {
>     var aabb = Physics.aabb( 4, 5, { x: 20, y: 9 } );
>     matches( aabb, { x: 20, y: 9, hw: 2, hh: 2.5 });
> });
> ```

spec.js looks to be the test code. Test actually doubles as documentation, and libraries like spec serve to make test code *read* like documentation. Additionally, test code is, of course, a collection of examples of how to use the code. Enjoy.

[Try reading other test code.](https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/tree/509362fd35abfc5959ad18d1ea824550de4e8ed4/test/spec)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll remember to look in test code moving forward. I didn't see anything that helped use the union function though. I'm using it as instructed in the documentation, but still can't join two bounding boxes.

Comment: @Thomas have you tried the source? https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/blob/509362fd35abfc5959ad18d1ea824550de4e8ed4/src/math/aabb.js#L102-125